# PHP/AJAX | POST Data Not Being Taken?

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a plugin that uses a click to edit AJAX POST request, I have the script all made up, but when I went to go test it, it never changed my database values that I was trying to modify, so I changed the URL you set to a function to report the request into my google console, it returns the following,

```
Object {name: "", value: "derp@derpp.com", pk: 23}
```

Here is the PHP script I am trying to AJAX to,

```
<? $query = " 
    UPDATE users SET email = '".$_POST['value']."' WHERE id = '".$_POST['pk']."'
";      
try 
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{  
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
```

My overall issue, is that the content is not being changed by the AJAX, I tested the script manually and everything works.

**EDIT**

I am not manually doing an AJAX request, its being used off of a plugin, called X-Editable The Documentation can be found [here](http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/docs.html)

Comment: Did you tried to use FireBug or any other tool to see what gets in return or what is error?

Comment: your code is open for **sql injection** use **prepared statement** instead

Comment: @NullPointer ok. I know. Please help me with my AJAX issue.

Comment: @AfnanBashir No, I've never used FireBug, to be honest I'm not even sure if there IS an error I have never really dealt with AJAX let alone jQuery this deep before. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: can you post your JS code?

Comment: Since I don't know the structure of your database I don't know for sure, BUT if your id column is in integer based column then you might do well to remove your single quotes around your value in the insert statement.

Comment: @Necro since you are not doing the ajax yourself, did you check the issue with single quotes around your primary key..

Comment: @KellyCopley Where should I be checking this? Do you mean around my $_POST in my PHP file?

Comment: yes, I will post a revised $query variable in an answer.. copy and paste where yours is now and see if it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you checked the data which you are sending is actually inside post request. I would check if i am using a proper jquery post request such as 
**$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});**

just sending post data doesn't helps. Moreover if you are not passing any dummy value such as javascript.getTime function its a good idea to use it coz sometime the xmlhttp object doesn't recognises as new query. 
Therefore your url should be "**url:'dummy='+dt.getTime()+'&var1='+$textbox1.val()**"
hope this helps you.

Comment: Timestamp dummy values are only necessary in GET requests

Comment: You don't need to put any "dummy" values into the url.. Especially since he is doing a POST request.. setting the cache control headers using php would be the answer if the requests are caching.

Comment: @Necro your problem with that is the extra "; at the end

Answer (score 0):

post data  type must be  application/x-www-urlencoded , if use $_POST function in php .

```
HTTP  /yourURI  HTTP/1.0
Content-Length:xxx
Content-Type:application/x-www-urlencoded
Connection:clsoe

name=&value=derp%40derpp.com&pk=23
```

can't post object to Server,as body...

```
HTTP  /yourURI  HTTP/1.0
Content-Length:xxx
Content-Type:application/json
Connection:clsoe

{name: "", value: "derp@derpp.com", pk: 23}
```

Answer (score -2):

revised query... If you have an integer based value, it can't be quoted;

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET email = '".$_POST['value']."' WHERE id = ".$_POST['pk'];
```

or using string replacement

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET email = '{$_POST['value']}' WHERE id = {$_POST['pk']}";
```

Comment: The ; in your statement will cause the PHP script to report an unexpected T_STRING..

Comment: If you are getting this error, it is not from the ;  this is tested and works on my end;

Comment: Wow, what a fail, posted a comment in the wrong answer. -_- sorry, and as far as the extra ; I copied exactly what you posted, which includes ".$_POST['pk']; maybe you didn't see? But you forgot the two "

Comment: @Necro the above comment just needed the "; taken off the end.. I'll update my answer to include a simpler version using php's string replacement instead of the concatenation operator.

Comment: I figured out my issue, for some reason, I was forced to put my POST in "", never had that issue before, may be something with the plugin? I have no clue, the fix was $_POST["value"] for example, thank you though.

Comment: **-1** Don't post solutions that perpetuate the SQL injection hell that this is.

Comment: I'm sorry, but he didn't ask about sql injection.. He wanted to know why his database wasn't being updated.. I gave a solid answer.. The reason his update was failing was because his id field was an integer and his query was giving a string value.. When the db couldn't find a key with that value it didn't report an error it just failed silently..